# Preferred Qt style for getters and setters

Tags: qt, coding-style

Is there a Qt-specific way to implement getters and setters?  Perhaps there are Qt macros or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q_PROPERTY

From the documentation ( https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html ):

> Qt provides a sophisticated property system similar to the ones supplied by some compiler vendors. However, as a compiler- and platform-independent library, Qt does not rely on non-standard compiler features like __property or [property]. The Qt solution works with any standard C++ compiler on every platform Qt supports. It is based on the Meta-Object System that also provides inter-object communication via signals and slots.

Answer (score 1):

standard setter and getter looks like this:

```
void YourClass::setSomeValue(const type &newValue) {
    if (newValue!=someValue) {
        someValue = newValue;
        emit someValueChanged(someValue);
        // some optional invocations to update sizeHint or schedule widget redrawing ... :
        update();
        updateGeometry();
    }
}

type YourClass::someValue() const {
    return someValue;
}
```

if you are looking for something like `@synthesize` in Objcetive C there is no such thing in Qt, but you can define your own macro (I do something like that sometimes).

Comment: This is substance, not style, but thanks for the useful template.

Comment: question was "way to implement getters and setters" so I don't understand your objections.

Comment: I was looking for the Q_PROPERTY usage that is more in keeping with Qt than your solution which is more vanilla C++.